# Display a text facing the camera and following a 3D object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, shader, perspective

I'm trying to draw two objects in OpenGL :

- a 3D object (let's say a cube) normally affected by the camera movement (with a perspective projection)
- a quad object with a string texture which has to follow the position of the 3D object, facing always the camera.

Here is my initial point : I can draw a cube and a string entity just on the top of it.

[image]

I now want to display the string always facing the camera.
As it is explained [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20140807/billboarding-vertex-shader-glsl/), I removed the rotation from my modelMatrix to make the text facing to me.

The text is indeed facing me, but it is not following the position of the cube when I move the camera... (NB : with the initial position of the cube, the position of the text seems to be OK).

[image]

[image]

I should be missing something...

---

Here are some snippets of my code :

- The vertex shader :

(when drawing the text, the uniform "isBillboarding" is set to 1, and when drawing the cube, the uniform "isBillboarding" is set to 0)

```
uniform mat4    transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4    projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4    viewMatrix;
uniform float   isBillboarding; // 0 for no, 1 for yes
[...]

attribute vec3  attribute_Position;
[...]

void main(void)
{
    mat4 modelView = viewMatrix * transformationMatrix;

    if (isBillboarding > 0.5) 
    {
        modelView[0][0] = 1;
        modelView[0][1] = 0;
        modelView[0][2] = 0;

        modelView[1][0] = 0;
        modelView[1][1] = -1;
        modelView[1][2] = 0;
    }

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelView * vec4(attribute_Position,1.0);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Transform the fourth column of `modelView` with the upper left 3x3 matrix before cutting it off.

Comment: I don't get you... What do I have to do ?

Comment: Something like `mv[3].xyz = mat3(mv) * mv[3].xyz`. No guarantees on the GLSL syntax, though. And then you can override the matrix.

Comment: Mmm... It seems a bit better but far from perfect : with a centered cube, it works fine with a roll, but with a pitch it is still not ok (the text is moving up and down, with the same left-right position). When trying with a not centered cube, the pitch looks the same, and when trying to do a roll, the text stays in the same position (although the cube is making rounds).

Comment: Ok, I may have overlooked something. Anyway, it is probably easier to get the screen space position to which you want to attach your text and use this in the shader. This is simply a transform with the inverse model-view-projection matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem :

The idea is to compute a model-View transformation matrix, which is the combinaison between the view matrix and a model matrix which reset the rotation of the view matrix (taking in account the translation).

I built a dedicated shader for my text object :

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(attribute_Position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);

    pass_textureCoords = attribute_TextureCoords;
    varying_Color = attribute_Color;
}
```

And I set the modelViewMatrix like this :

```
Matrix4f viewMatrix = TransformationMatrix.createViewMatrix(renderer.camera); // or how ever you want to do it
Matrix4f modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
modelMatrix.setIdentity();
// set the translation
modelMatrix.m30 = entityTranslation.x;
modelMatrix.m31 = entityTranslation.y;
modelMatrix.m32 = entityTranslation.z;
// reset the rotation
modelMatrix.m00 = viewMatrix.m00;
modelMatrix.m01 = viewMatrix.m10;
modelMatrix.m02 = viewMatrix.m20;
modelMatrix.m10 = viewMatrix.m01;
modelMatrix.m11 = viewMatrix.m11;
modelMatrix.m12 = viewMatrix.m21;
modelMatrix.m20 = viewMatrix.m02;
modelMatrix.m21 = viewMatrix.m12;
modelMatrix.m22 = viewMatrix.m22;
// compute modelViewMatrix
Matrix4f modelViewMatrix = modelMatrix;
modelViewMatrix.mul(viewMatrix);

shaderProgram.loadModelViewMatrix(modelViewMatrix);
```

This does the trick for me